# .xprofile broken in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: .profile

Today I upgraded to latest Ubuntu 18.04 from 17.10, but computer says `~/.xprofile` has syntax error, and could not use desktop. Only a movable mouse icon on a violet color blank screen.

When I checked the .xprofile in home directory, it only contains 4 lines, seems broken. But where could I find a complete .xprofile to replace the old one? Please help.

My .xprofile  only have these four lines:

```
#setup XIM environment
export GTK_IM_MODULE=fcitx
export QT_IM_MODULE=fcitx
export XMODIFIERS="@im=fcitx"
```

Comment: Can we see the four lines therein?

Comment: sure, I edit the problem, add  the .xprofile, as you could see

Comment: I'd suggest you to create a new user, login with his credentials once, so you will have a reference profile. Then have a look at his `.xprofile`.

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs In the very beginning, I use Unity. when in 17.10 I updated to gnome. Now for simplicity,  I remove Gnome, replace with Unity.  I guess the problem must caused by their differences.

Comment: @GeorgeUdosensure, I edit the problem, add the .xprofile, as you could see –

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just got around to upgrading from 16.04 to 18.04 today and ran into the same issue. It seems that I had some settings from some older software that I stopped using but never removed from the `.xprofile`. Anyhow, long story short, I simple `mv .xprofile .xprofile_BAK` and restarted which happened to remove the errors. You will need to figure out exactly how to migrate things over from that .xprofile if you need them migrated, other than that you can live without it.

Comment: I appreciete your advice, however I simply changed the desktop environment, that really works.According to my poor understanding, this is because of conflicts between Gnome and Unity. 

Thus, I choose to change the default desktop environment. For example, you can install KDE plasma, this problem will be solved.

Answer (score 1):

According to my poor understanding, this is because of conflicts between Gnome and Unity.

Thus, I choose to change the default desktop environment. For example, you can install KDE plasma, this problem will be solved.